# JavaFX: Label changes location when resizing window

Tags: java, label, fxml, borderpane

I have a very simple Label with the text "Hello World" added to a parent object and I want to add that in the center-middle of a BorderPane.

Label starts a bit off-center, and when window is resized the label/parent "snaps" into place where I want it to be. Why does it behave like this?

FXML class:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="pane" fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<center>
    <MapCanvas fx:id="map" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

MapCanvas class:

```
public class MapCanvas extends Parent {
    public MapCanvas() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        Label world = new Label();
        world.setText("Hello world");
        world.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", 24));
        getChildren().add(world);
    }
}
```

Generic JavaFX Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Model model = new Model();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending `Parent`? Unless you have a very good reason it's probably wrong to extend a layout pane, but even if you do - why not `Group` or `Pane`?

Comment: In the future I want to be able to draw a map, and I was looking for an alternative to a JComponent for JavaFX.